# windows service: Read from different servers with different settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

**Scenario**:

- Read files from different servers. Each server provide files with different **format**, **extension** and **data**.
- The reading process is **periodically different for each server** (per minute, hour, weekly, monthly).
- There should be config file (or whatever) to set the configuration related to "File format", "File extension", "Server credentials".

---

**My Implementation**:

I wrote an application to read these different files depending on configuration set as follow:

```
interface IServer
{
    // Common implementation
}

[ServerPath("anyLocation")]
[FileDelimiter(",")]
[FileSearchPattern("*.txt")]
class Server2 : IServer
{
    // Specific implementation
}

[ServerPath("anyLocation")]
[FileDelimiter("|")]
[FileSearchPattern("*.csv")]
class Server1 : IServer
{
    // Specific implementation
}
```

**Questions**:

- Should I use a windows service to run this app?
- The settings I set as attributes should exists as settings accessible to the user, How to do?
- Most importantly, I don't know if I should use a separate service for each server, taking into consideration that reading time may interfere (what happen in that case?). I still prefer to have a single service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a windows service for this kind of problem.

Create a simple console application that accepts a commend line parameter to specify the desired target (server) and read the according configuration from a simple App.config instead of hardcoding it into your app.

Run your console app useing Scheduled Tasks - this will give you fine grained scheduling control, built in monitoring and error tracking without any additional code.

Comment: thanx for your answer.
I am aware of the settings that should be set in a config file, but my concern is that the reading process should be executed automatically based on the settings. A windows service, a scheduled task or other automated technique.
and for other reasons, we didn't use SSIS.

Comment: SSIS sounded like a perfect fit for this. Anyway I wouldn't recommend to create a windows service ... unless you really need to process hundreds of different sources. If you need an Enterprise class solution you could also look into MS BizTalk server. Its architecture is basically the same as your planned service would need. [BlueIntergrator](http://blueintegrator.com/) might be an inexpensive alternative.